# printf is not showing up in the console Java Eclipse 19

Tags: java, eclipse, console, printf, system.out

Every time I run my Java code on Eclipse JDK 19, the console says it's terminated but nothing shows up in there.

```
package rnt;

import java.util.Arrays;
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for(int number = 1; number < 10; number++) {
            for(int multiplier = 1; multiplier < 1; multiplier++) {
                System.out.printf("%d X %d = %d \n", number, multiplier, number * multiplier);
            }
        }   

    }
}
```

[Image of my console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPZDq.png)

So far I tried checking the compiler in the properties of my project, and [everything is running on version 19.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTGQW.png) I tried changing it to version 18 but still getting the same results.

I checked if Eclipse needs updates and as of right now, everything is updated.

I notice I tend to get errors whenever I try to use `System.out.printf` when I code in Java. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I'm following along with this [video](https://youtu.be/A74TOX803D0?t=9629) it's just not working on mine.

Is there any reason why `System.out.printf` is like this in Java?

Comment: This is when you would take advantage of Eclipse containing an actual debugger you can use to step through your code, line by line. Use the Debug menu instead of the Run menu to make use of it, after setting a breakpoint in your source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong the printf statement. It's the inner for loop that's wrong. The variable multiplier is initialised as 1, and the condition is < 1.

The loop will never run because the condition is never met. As you're printing table, correct the inner for loop to:

```java
for(int multiplier = 1; multiplier <= 10; multiplier++)
```